# How is of being used in this sentence

Tags: prepositions

> He took aim especially at Germany, highlighting in particular the incongruity between its military spending and huge trade surplus with the U.S. A relatively recent dimension to the diatribe is the attack on Germany’s large imports of gas from Russia, a divisive issue within Europe, particularly after the threats posed by Moscow’s regional ambitions. Besides putting Chancellor Angela Merkel in a spot, it served to deflect attention [ from criticism across the Atlantic **of** Mr. Trump’s proximity to Russian President Vladimir Putin and their bilateral meeting in
>    Helsinki.]

What does the bracketed part mean?

Comment: can you be a bit more specific about what is the particular problem with that part. I see some difficult words, but these are easily checked in a dictionary. The structure "critisism of something" is just the usual "of"

Comment: https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/transatlantic-rift/article24427685.ece

Comment: @JamesK  link is provided.

Answer (score 2):

Of is being used in one of its regular prepositional meanings.

"criticism of her hair" = saying her hair is bad.

I think this can be analysed as a form of "objective genitive" with a noun indicating an action (criticism  = the act of criticising) and the noun functioning as the object using a genitive form (of ...)

So in the example, we have "criticism  [...] of [...] Trump's proximity to Putin"  = "saying Trump's proximity to Putin is bad".

The criticism is coming from across the Atlantic (ie from critics in America as Trump is currently in Europe)

Comment: Yep. The criticism is coming from across the Atlantic; the criticism is being made about Trump's closeness to Putin.